# skaffold init using docker compose configuration fails with "Nil Pointer Dereference" error

Tags: docker-compose, skaffold, kompose

I am trying to generate skaffold configuration for docker-compose configuration using the following init command

```
+ skaffold init --compose-file docker-compose.yml --verbosity=info
```

**Expected behavior:**

The command should generate k8s manifests based on the docker-compose configuration and should generate skaffold configuration on issue of "skaffold init" command

**Actual behavior:**

This fails with the following "nil pointer deference" error

```
time="2019-12-11T15:44:08Z" level=info msg="generating skaffold config"
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

**Information:**

Skaffold version: v0.37.0
Operating system: RHEL
Contents of skaffold.yaml: No skaffold.yaml

**Steps to reproduce the behavior:**

Run "skaffold init --compose-file docker-compose.yml --verbosity=info" with a basic docker compose file.

Please suggest me to resolve this issue